Facing issues with recording audio for 2 applications in Linux Mint
I am currently building a small-scale project to record audio during online meetings/calls with clients and use the SpeechRecognition package in Python to get the transcript.
To record audio, I started off by using PyAudio, but I faced several issues in finding my device while listing the microphone
def check_microphones():
    print("Available microphones:")
    for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
        print(f"{index}: {name}")

So, I thought to directly record audio using arecord
command = ['arecord', '--device=hw:1,0', '--format', 'S16_LE', '--rate', '44100', '-c2', "audio/output.wav"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command)

While this worked during testing, but when I actually used it alongside an online meeting, I frequently encountered the error arecord: main:831: audio open error: Device or resource busy
I have tried following the steps mentioned on this post and this, but none of them were able to solve my issue
